# Locating .Storedata file in Mac

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have build an iPhone project on my IOS device. I used core data for storing some datas. When  i  build, it is woking. I just need to locate this .storedata file and when i traced, the location is /var/mobile/Applications/211B3C9E-82B3-4304-90D2-EE5E4337D9F1/Documents/MyProject.storedata. I opened all the hidden files in the machine but i am unable to locate the specified path for the device. I could locate the file when i build it in simulator. Can anyone suggest me some way to locate this file?

Comment: are you talking about the sqlite database that CoreData creates?

Comment: @Chris not sqlite. i used core data.

Comment: yeah CoreData still creates a .sqlite database in the user/library/applicationsupport/iphonesimulator/5.1/applications/(APPKEY)/documents/   you can use sqlitemanager in firefox to look at its contents

Comment: @Chris-yeah that is in simulator... but i buid it on ios device... so where will be its location?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running it on the device then you're creating the database on the device. You need an iPhone file explorer (I use [iFunBox](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CEYQFjAA&url=http://www.i-funbox.com/&ei=f1IAUL71JKnk2wWF0_XABA&usg=AFQjCNF9USijQCeC-BUxnX0jN34pGFQamw)).